# How to Trigger the Jet Smart Filters, without changing the URL?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, navbar, elementor, jet-engine

I'm working on a Wordpress-Website and have run into a specific challenge with the filtering system  created using Smart Filters that I hope someone can help me with.

I have implemented a filter on the website, and there's a particular requirement from my client: they want to trigger one of the taxonomies directly from the navbar. However, when I create links with the corresponding slug for this purpose, it alters the URL. Consequently, when users either clear the filter or choose a different category within it, the page doesn't display any results.

To address this, I attempted to design a radio filter that mimics the appearance of the navigation menu, which didn't work that well.

My goal is to allow users to trigger this taxonomy from the navbar without redirecting or altering the URL. Is there any method or workaround that would enable me to achieve this? Your insights and suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Also I want to be able to do the same thing using a breadcrumb inside a Post. This breadcrumb is created using a dynamic field which displays the categories of a hierarchical taxonomy that I created (The same taxonomy to be triggered by the navbar).

Thank you in advance!